# Automate Chrome with Google Script?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

I am purely an amateur coder so please forgive any stupid questions !

I know a little bit of VBA and can pull together code which:
(a) creates a new Internet Explorer object
(b) navigates to a given URL
(c) accesses specific div tags and returns their innertext

However I would be really interested to know how to do a similar thing using Google Scripts and Google Chrome instead ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Apps Script runs in Google's servers. VBA runs on your machine. If you want to use GAS to manipulate the browser for the user, the only portion will be that which creates client side JavaScript in an `HtmlOutput` and renders it. If you just need programmatic external requests, see the answer about `UrlFetchApp`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take a look at the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) class object in Google Apps Script and specifically the [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)) method.

Here is an example to get you started

```
// Make a GET request and log the returned content.
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.google.com/');
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

To analyse the contents of the page I would suggest using the [XMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service) class in addition to the above method. See the following for an example:

```
// Log the title and labels for the first page of blog posts on the G Suite Developer blog.
function parseXml() {
  var url = 'https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/atom.xml';
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var atom = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

  var entries = document.getRootElement().getChildren('entry', atom);
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var title = entries[i].getChild('title', atom).getText();
    var categoryElements = entries[i].getChildren('category', atom);
    var labels = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < categoryElements.length; j++) {
      labels.push(categoryElements[j].getAttribute('term').getValue());
    }
    Logger.log('%s (%s)', title, labels.join(', '));
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks.  I will have a look later with a cool, damp towel on my brow :)